# Message passed between friends in a library

Tags: cipher

Mary met her friend Jenny in the library. They gossiped about various things and then each chose a book and went to separate corners of the library and sat down to read. After half an hour Jenny went to Mary to say goodbye and gave her an encrypted message, the one shown below.

217622-1361336262576310-622-2526316832621

What was the message in words?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Plaintext:

> This bibliophile is polyglot

Substitution key:

> ```
>  n  m  l  k  j  i  h  g  f  e  d  c  b
>  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13
>
>  a  z  y  x  w  v  u  t  s  r  q  p  o
> 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26
> ```

Solve path:

> Assumed the two short words were `THIS` and `IS`, noticed the 21-22 and 7-6 pairs in the first word were consecutive just as the pairs `ST` and `HI` in `THIS`, and the rest of the solution followed.

Comment: This puzzle has a very old-school vibe.